# Switching between keyboards in mac - shortcut key?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, language

What shortcut key do you use to switch keyboards on your mac? Windows uses <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and on the Mac the default is <kbd>Apple</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. However, that's also the shortcut for spotlight.

I ended up disabling the spotlight shortcut.

What's your preferred keyboard switching shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Mac I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to switch languages. I was already used to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> from Windows and, since <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> alone wasn't a valid combo, I just added the nearest key (<kbd>Z</kbd>).

Comment: Looks like a reasonable thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Since I use GNOME-DO on Linux, and used to use Google Desktop Search on Windows, I changed the spotlight shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, and use <kbd>Apple</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> for language switching.