# OSX shortcut for switching input language working erratically

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I'm using the keyboard shortcut option+shift+command+L to select the next source in the input menu. When I'm doing language work I frequently have to switch between Arabic and English keyboard layouts/languages.

When I switch keyboards using this shortcut the change doesn't always take effect. Sometimes I have to press the shortcut 3 or more times to get the text that I'm entering to be in the desired language.  Every time I press the shortcut the flag for the keyboard layout changes as expected, but this doesn't always correspond with what that actual keyboard input is when I start typing (sometimes when the arabic language flag is shown the keyboard layout is still in english and vice versa).

Interestingly, when I switch the keyboard using the mouse and clicking on the flag in the menu bar, everything works exactly as expected. The flag changes and the typing input always matches the flag show in in the menu.

I also have the "automatically switch to document's input source" box unchecked — found in System Preferences > Keyboard.

I'm using a Macbook Pro Retina Mac OSX 10.9.4

Comment: Related: [Switching between keyboards in mac - shortcut key?](http://superuser.com/q/13481/87805)

Answer (score 0):

I also have to change input source 50 times a day and came up with a useful method. [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) app might help you with this by customising Mac keybord settings.

It provides very finely customization of key repeat rate and you can also accelerate key repeat rate beyond the limits of OS X.

For example:

> Open "Key Repeat" tab and change "Delay Until Repeat" and "Key Repeat".

[image: Karabiner OSX app]

For more details, check [manual](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en) page and [my blog](http://seoul-life.blog.jp/archives/30821467.html).

---

Updated 12.01.2021 for Karabiner-Elements. The app does not manage it anymore, here's the [official docs](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/help/how-to/key-repeat/).

Comment: It would be a good idea to disclose your affiliation more explicitly.

Comment: How about explain your system in your answer?  I see no reason you need to link to your blog to answer this question.

Comment: I wasn't paying attention I erronously approved the edit pending for this answer.

Comment: That looks like it might be useful, but Super User is intended to be the destination for answers rather than a collection of links to answers somewhere else.  Answers should be self-contained.  External links can break, in which case your answer would have no value.  That's why your answer is starting to collect downvotes.  Please add the essential information to your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  You can copy and paste key text.  The link will take people who are interested to your blog for the full story with pictures.